# How can I create a new process for each element of a matrix?

Tags: c, matrix, process, fork, pid

How can I use the fork() function to create a matrix with processes, each containing a unique process ID (PID), and then print the matrix? I have attempted to implement this code, but I am getting an infinite loop and am unsure how to correctly use fork(). Can someone explain how fork() works and provide an example for my specific use case? Thank you!

Here is my current code:

```
pid_t forking;
for (int i = 0; i < ROW; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < COL; j++){
            forking = fork();
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show your code, explain what it tries to do and what error or incorrect behaviour it has.

Comment: I'm just *guessing* but perhaps you let the child-processes continue after their work? You must remember to `exit` the child-processes once they're done with their processing.

Comment: @kaylum I added code, I left it out only because the most important part is missing and, as I explained in the question, I can't add.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude how can i add the exit in my code?

Comment: Would suggest you read the [manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) and look at the linked examples. What you have is called a "fork bomb" - every child process also calls `fork` in a loop. You need to add code after the `fork` call to seperate out what the parent process does (continue `fork` loop) and what the child process should do (e.g. print something).

Answer (score 2):

Now when we can see some code, my guess seems to be correct. If seems you misunderstand how [`fork`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) works...

If successful it actually returns *twice!* Once in the parent process, and once in the child process. In the child process you should not continue the loop, but instead do some "work" and then `exit`. The parent process should continue the loops to create processes and then do its own processing before finally *reap* all child processes.

In short something like:

```
pid_t pid_matrix[ROW][COL];

for (size_t row = 0; row < ROW; ++row)
{
    for (size_t col = 0; col < COL; ++col)
    {
        pid_matrix[row][col] = fork();

        if (pid_matrix[row][col] == -1)
        {
            // Error! Handle it some nice way
        }
        else if (pid_matrix[row][col] == 0)
        {
            // In the child process...
            // TODO: Do some work here!
            printf("In a new child process with pid %d\n", getpid());

            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);  // Terminate the child process

            // Note that because the child-process have now exited,
            // the loop will not continue
        }
        else
        {
            // In the parent process
            printf("Created a new process with pid %d\n", pid_matrix[row][col]);

            // Note that we don't exit or do anything special here
            // This will let the loops continue as normal
        }
    }
}
```

<sub>[How to *reap* (release resources) of the child-processes is left as an exercise to the reader]</sub>

Comment: At the end, the parent process should `wait` for the children to terminate.